# How to compare (greater than less than) objects of unknown type?

Tags: c#, .net

Need to make static Sorter class (bubble sort, insertion sort, etc...) to sort a collection (array, list, whatever I want) of objects that I don't know the type of at compile time.

Understanding the sorting algorithms is not my issue, i just want to know how to compare two objects (say strings) without making my Bubble Sort method have to check the type and then redirect to code block that works for that data type.

How can I go about making one bubble sort method/code block that will work for any data type so long as all the objects stored in the collection are of the same type.

I can make sorting algorithms work with int because that is intuitive and you can compare ints with basic operands like < and >=. I dont really know how to even begin going about making a method that will sort any type. Ive seen peopl mention implementing Comparable or Enumerable Interfaces but what if I was passing an array of objects that I have never seen before or I dont know about before I compile my end of the code?

Comment: What type will be the items passed in to your static Sorter? Will it be `object` or will it be generic?

Comment: I can pass them however I wish to. I can pass an object array filled with ints if I wanted. Or an generic array of ints. Only requirement is that it must be a collection and all the objects in the collection are of the same type. I assume this problem would be much easier if I just pass an object collection to the static class methods.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs **and expected results based on those sample inputs**. At least 4 sets of sample inputs would be best.

Comment: C# already includes a sort implementation that handles this as part of LINQ - `OrderBy`. For any collection of objects, you can use `OrderBy(x => x)` to sort it. See the [C# Rererence Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) for the implementation in the .Net Framework.

Comment: Great tip on the built in OrderBy. Unfortunately I was just trying to learn C# and this was an interesting problem i couldn't solve. I wanted to make a class of sorters, so I could eventually test millisecond timings of each sort algorithm  on different object arrays. I wanted to be able to show how BubbleSort will take longer in most cases when compared to something like standard QuickSort. I do however appreciate the help and tips you have given and will store OrderBy in the back of my mind. Sorry for the confusion in my OP question. My bad fam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to write a generic method that enforces that the type implements the `IComparable<T>` interface, and then you can use the `.CompareTo` method of that interface to do the sorting.

For example:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    var results = input.ToList();

    for (int counter = 0; counter < results.Count; counter++)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < results.Count - 1; index++)
        {
            if (results[index].CompareTo(results[index + 1]) > 0)
            {
                var temp = results[index + 1];
                results[index + 1] = results[index];
                results[index] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Example usage:

```
private static void Main()
{
    string[] strArray = {"will", "this", "sort", "correctly"};
    int[] intArray = {3, 4, 7, 2, 1};

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Sort(strArray)));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Sort(intArray)));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hmm, this is VERY interesting

[code]
private static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) where T : IComparable<T>
[code]

Can you link to a docu or something that explains this a bit further....very confused about the use of the 'where' keyword and Interfaces in general.

Comment: But for interfaces we need to write the compareTo methods ourseolves right? How will I do this if I dunno the object being passed? What if I don't want to write comparsion methods for every type out there? there must be an easier way right?

Comment: You can find info on interfaces [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) and information on Constraints on type parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: No, you don't have to write anything else. At the end of the signature it says `where T : IComparable<T>`, which is basically saying that you can pass any type to this class that implements `IComparable<>`. Most classes that can be sorted will have already implemented this interface. Are you saying you want to sort classes that don't implement this?

Comment: Many of the built in types in .Net already implement the `IComparable` interface, like `string` and `int`.

Comment: Right on Mr. Rufus L! Thanks alot. Looks like its time to crack open my reference materials and learn this hardcore. Thank for sending me in the right direction! Answer will be marked!

Comment: Thank you as well Kateract! I appreciate the link! and inside info on .net generic types already including the Interface! Much thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using [`IComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
public static void BubbleSort<T>(T[] array, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    for (int i = array.Length; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        bool swapped = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (comparer.Compare(array[j + 1], array[j]) < 0)
            {
                T temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }

        if (swapped == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The important line here is:

```
 if (comparer.Compare(array[j + 1], array[j]) < 0)
```

This is like writing

```
 if (array[j + 1] < array[j])
```

Except that it lets you use your own comparison function that may be completely unrelated to what class T itself defines for `operator <` or `IComparable<T>.CompareTo`.

For example, you can sort objects of mixed types by their *type name*.

```
class TypeNameComparer : IComparer<object>
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        x.GetType().FullName.CompareTo(y.GetType().FullName);
    }
}

private static void Main()
{
    object[] mixed = {42, "Hello, world!", System.Guid.NewGuid()};
    BubbleSort(mixed, new TypeNameComparer());

    foreach (object obj in mixed)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

which will produce an output like:

```
b5852625-cee2-479d-bfd5-7d3f01e78529
42
Hello, world!
```

Because `System.Guid`, `System.Int32`, and `System.String` are in ASCIIbetical order.